# PHP array to string (array_push)

Tags: php

When I do array push I get array to string convertion error. But array_merge doesn't work.

/page1.php/

I get values from a form on a previous page, $_POST['checkBox'] is set as an array.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkBox'])) {

    $checkBoxValue = $_POST['checkBox'];

    if (!$session->exists('results')){
        $session->set('results', $checkBoxValue);
    }else if ($session->exists('results')){
        $session->add('results', $checkBoxValue);
    }
    header('Location: export.php');
}

if (!$session->exists('results')) {

    echo "U heeft geen adviezen gekozen.";

} else if ($session->exists('results')) {

    echo "<b>U heeft de volgende adviezen gekozen: </b><br>";

    foreach ($session->get('results') as $value) {
        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

/$session->add()/

Here my method to array_push.

```
public static function add($key, $value){
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])){
        array_push($_SESSION[$key], $value);
    }
}
```

/error/

I print_r my sessions and this is the error I get:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in ...


Array
(
    [login] => 1
    [data] => 1
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem ipsum
            [1] => Lorem 
            [2] => Lorem ipsum
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lorem 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The error is here: `echo $value.'<br>';` because You have array at `[3]` element of $_SESSION['results'], and you try to echoing it as string.

Comment: You should check what line the notice refers to. Then you will probably see your `array_push` is not the problem, but something else.

Comment: _Small Note and in answer to your question on @Praveen's answer_ Even the PHP manual mentions that if you are only adding one item to the array it is more efficient to use `$_SESSION[$key][] = $value;` as you dont have the overhead of calling a function

Comment: We tried this but we still have the array to string problem

Comment: Okay @Chris.P Don't lose your cool.  We have to prune the new duplicate pages.  Please carefully craft your question and I am sure we can help you.

Comment: Please show us your html form so that we can see the `name` attribute.  Or better yet, show us the `$_POST` array.  Since your `if` is `!$session->exists('results')`, you can more simply write `} else {` for the opposite logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaken here. The variable `$checkBoxValue` might be of type array but the `results` in Session is not an array. To use this as an array, you'll have to declare it as an array. The below code should resolve the issue:

```
public static function add($key, $value) {
    $array = array();
    if (!empty($_SESSION[$key]) && is_array($_SESSION[$key])){
        $array = $_SESSION[$key];
    } else {
        $_SESSION[$key] = array();
    }
    array_push($array, $value);
    $_SESSION[$key] = $array;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check comment 1. The issue is not even in this piece of code :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the issue we are trying to fix.
as RiggsFolly said

Comment: Yes. But instead of using set and add function, I have involved the functionality of both in my single function logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use array_push() to insert a "$key" => "$value" pair into an array, it can be done using the following:

```
$_SESSION[$key] = $value;
```

It is not necessary to use array_push

Comment: If I do this the already set values in the session get replaced by the new values instead of being added to it.